# Trying to make a KML file in Python

Tags: python, kml

I'm still very new to python, i am trying to export the locations on a list (List2) into a kml file which will then display the results on google maps. I have no idea really what i am doing and atm all i am getting is a syntax error around every ,", symbol. Can someone help me with this please.

```
KMLFile = open("KML.txt", "w")
f.write("<KML_File>\n")
f.write("<Document>\n")
for line in List2:
    f.write("   <Placemark>")
    f.write("       <decription>" + str(row[0]) + "</description>")
    f.write("       <Point>")
    f.write("          <coordinates>" + str(row[2]) + str(row[1])"</coordinates>")
    f.write("       </Point>")
    f.write("   </Placemark>")
f.write("</Document>\n")
f.write("</kml>\n")
KMLFile = close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief:

- You should change `KMLFile` to `f` or vice versa.
- You should call the `close()` method like this : `f.close()`.

Your corrected code:

```
f = open("KML.txt", "w")
f.write("<KML_File>\n")
f.write("<Document>\n")
for line in List2:
    f.write("\t<Placemark>")
    f.write("\t\t<decription>" + str(row[0]) + "</description>")
    f.write("\t\t<Point>")
    f.write("\t\t\t<coordinates>" + str(row[2]) + str(row[1]) + "</coordinates>")
    f.write("\t\t</Point>")
    f.write("\t</Placemark>")
f.write("</Document>\n")
f.write("</kml>\n")
f.close()
```

In addition, if you do not want to write the `f.close()` line and let python manage the file closure:

```
with open("KML.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("<KML_File>\n")
    f.write("<Document>\n")
    for line in List2:
        f.write("\t<Placemark>")
        f.write("\t\t<decription>" + str(row[0]) + "</description>")
        f.write("\t\t<Point>")
        f.write("\t\t\t<coordinates>" + str(row[2]) + str(row[1]) + "</coordinates>")
        f.write("\t\t</Point>")
        f.write("\t</Placemark>")
    f.write("</Document>\n")
    f.write("</kml>\n")
```

Eventually, if you do not want to have many `+` into your `f.write()` lines, you can also opt for the `format()` method:

```
f.write("\t\t\t<coordinates>{}{}/coordinates>".format(row[2], row[1]))
```

Comment: I am a complete derp omg, ok i have changed that, but i still keep getting a syntax error in this part of the code:

f.write("\t\t\t<coordinates>" + str(row[2]) + str(row[1])"</coordinates>")

in the very last ,", symbol for some reason

Answer (score 13):

Hard-coding XML output to create a KML file in a series of print statements is error-prone and hard to maintain. Rather use a Python KML library such as [simplekml](http://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [pyKML](https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/) to generate the KML. The simplekml API simplifies writing KML and produces valid KML with code that is cleaner and easier to understand.

```python
import simplekml

# list2 = ...some assignment with list of point data elements
kml = simplekml.Kml()
for desc,lat,lon in list2:
    kml.newpoint(description=desc,
        coords=[(lon, lat)])  # lon, lat, optional height
# save KML to a file
kml.save("test.kml")
```

Using this test input for a single point:

```
list2 = [ ('description', 51.500152, -0.126236) ] # description, lat, lon
```

The KML output would be this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="feat_1">
        <Placemark id="feat_2">
            <description>description</description>
            <Point id="geom_0">
                <coordinates>-0.126236,51.500152,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you haven't defined the variable `f` which should reference the file-object you want to write to. You could either do

```
f = open("KML.txt", "w")
f.write("<KML_File>\n")
...
f.close()
```

or better:

```
with open("KML.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("<KML_File>\n")
    ...
```

which makes sure to always close the file even if some code in between fails.

For writing XML-files you might want to take a look at the Python [xml-package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#module-xml).

Comment: I am a complete derp omg, ok i have changed that, but i still keep getting a syntax error in this part of the code: f.write("\t\t\t<coordinates>" + str(row[2]) + str(row[1])"</coordinates>") in the very last ,", symbol for some reason

Comment: You forgot a `+` sign after `str(row[1])`

Answer (score -1):

```
import geopandas as gpd

polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df) 
polys.to_file(r'../docs/database.kml', driver = 'KML')
```

- df should contain description, geometry, name.

Comment: Geopandas uses Fiona which doesn't support KML. So this will not work.